# API User Search

Tags: deezer

I'm looking for a way to search for users via the Deezer API. Currently it looks like there's no search on users, unless I've missed something in the docs? Lookup via email would be great too.

Are there any plans to add these sorts of features?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search method on users has been deprecated temporarily, we have to re-implement it and will be available in a few time, sorry for the inconvenience!